# Can't pass setCount function with useCallback

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a setCount function to a Button component using useCallback but nothing is changed in the input.[cod](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv6x1mv3rl)

```
   const Button = memo(({ value, useValue }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        value={value}
        onChange={({ target }) => {
          useValue(target.value);
        }}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const SetCount = useCallback(() => setCount, []);

  return (
    <section className="counter">
      <h1>Счётчик: {count}</h1>
      <Button value={count} useValue={SetCount}>
        -
      </Button>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback` memoizes specified callback. `() => setCount` callback is a no-op because `setCount` isn't called. This would work with `useMemo` because it's supposed to return a callback:

```
const SetCount = useMemo(() => setCount, []);
```

Neither of them are needed here. `useState` setter functions are constant and supposed to be passed as callbacks.

It should be:

```
<Button value={count} useValue={setCount}>
```

Comment: I do not understand why useMemo and useCallback.Is there an example?

Comment: See the reference, it already provides necessary examples, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback . `useMemo` accepts a function and returns its memoized result. `useCallback` just returns memoized result. `useCallback(value)` is a shortcut for `useMemo(() => value)` with meaningful name (it can accept any values but is intended to be used with callbacks). The behaviour you were after is provided by useMemo, otherwise setCount won't be called.

Comment: Thank you so much.